# Vector memory on Program close c++

Tags: c++, vector

I just had a quick question about using vectors when programming in c++. If you create a vector do you need to clear it or delete it before the program closes or will the vector be deleted and the memory freed when you close the program?

Thanks

Steven

Comment: depends on how you declared/initialized the instance and on your OS too.

Comment: Replace `vector` with an `int` or some other built-in type. It is the same, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you declared your vector.

1. If you use RAII (your vector is a stack object, `std::vector<...> myVec;`)
2. Or if you created it on the heap (`std::vector<...>* myVec = new std::vector<...>();`)

In the first case you will not have to do anything, because as soon as the vector runs out of scope (which is always the case when the application terminates), its desctructor will be called and it will clean up its ressoruces.

In the second case youll have to call `delete myVec;` so 1) the vector becomes uninitialized (the same as in the first case, destructor gets called etc.) and 2) the memory of your vector becomes freed.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply declare a vector, eg.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
```

It has *automatic storage duration* and the destructor will be called when it goes out of scope.

If you have used `new`, then you should use `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create it with `new` (which, usually, you shouldn't), then there's no need to do anything. It will be destroyed automatically according at the end of its lifetime, and the destructor will automatically release its memory.

If you created it with `new` then, for good order, you *should* make sure you delete it before the program ends. If you don't, then most modern operating systems will release the memory anyway; but allowing it to leak might make it harder to track down problematic leaks, and could cause issues on exotic operating systems.

In either case, there's no need to clear it; the destructor will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question touches two different things. OS and *life of object* within the program**

**OS part**: Generally speaking, in modern OSes you do not have to do anything. Any decent modern operating system dealloactes memory after process ends. Even the dynamically allocated/requested.

This is one of the reasons why windows 95 was so faulty and unstable over time. It did not do it. So if the application would leak out memory (and apps did and do it pretty much all the time), it would be hogged permanently.

**c++**: Now when you have modern c++ containers and well designed and implemented objects, they all have written destructors. So they are polite and nice and they free their own memory. And they are destructed basically on two conditions. If you do not allocate it dynamically e.g. via `new` compiler knows when the life of object ends. It goes out of scope. And it calls the destructor automatically. If you use `new` you need to call `delete` afterwards.

So the answer is. The object can clean up after it self not only when application closes, but when the object *dies*. If you however leak memory, you still should be safe, then the process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

When you "close a program" it is the responsibility of the operating system to free any memory the program was using.  No matter how you created your vector, when you "close the program" all the memory will be restored.  You do not have to worry about anything.

However, in large programs, you should not rely on a user "closing the program" to free up memory used.  If you use the keyword "new" you are responsible for calling "delete."  If you declared a vector without "new" you do not have to do anything as the destructor will automatically handle memory deallocation for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is far more common to see something like this:

```
std::vector<MyType*> container;
```

Rather than something like this:

```
std::vector<MyType> *container = new std::vector<MyType>;
```

In fact, I have never in my 15+ years of programming seen the latter.  The latter would defeat the purpose of an STL container in my opinion.  I guess it is possible that someone might still be doing some programming for windows 95, but that seems highly unlikely.  The most common issue with any STL container is when you have a container of pointers.  Since containers cannot be heterogeneous, it is fairly common to see or use containers of pointers to the base, interface class of objects.  In that case, you would have to loop and delete every object prior to erasing things from the vector.  If the vector loses scope it will not know how to delete the objects that are pointed to.  It will only clean up the memory for the pointers that have been added.

If you do the following, in a function or in a class declaration then you have no memory cleanup obligations.  The STL implementation either works properly or it doesn't.  Either way, there is nothing more that the programmer could do except to define your own custom allocator:

```
std::vector<MyType> container; // then add some stuff to it
```

I'm not going to get into boost or C++11, but FYI there are special container types within boost that are designed to make the user of containers of pointers easier.  I'm not sure if there are any new C++ 11 features that provide that capability.  Personally, I would recommend that you not worry about whether OSs will do the right thing when a program leaks memory.  Don't leak memory.  If you are working with an embedded OS, read the documentation and make sure you know whether its STL implementation has any limitations.